# ¡Bienvenidos a este su sitio!

Tags: discusión, temática, gerente-de-comunidad, anuncios

Primeramente, quiero agradecer a todos los que han participado en este Meta con sugerencias, opiniones, y pensamientos. Es justamente lo que esperaba ver.  Me alegra saber que hay varios aquí que quieren que nuestro sitio sea un éxito. No he tenido mucha oportunidad de escribir aquí tanto como he querido pero me esforcé de todos modos para contribuir esta publicación.

### ¿Quién es Juan M?

Permítanme decir unas palabras sobre quién soy para poder presentarme de manera adecuada.

Llevo 10 años proveyendo dirección a comunidades virtuales.  Traigo conmigo esa experiencia para poder apoyar a nuestros miembros y a Stack Overflow a tener una comunidad sin igual.  He dirigido comunidades de diferentes temáticas como automóviles, construcción, el hogar, diseño, teléfonos móviles y aplicaciones para iOS entre otras.

Mi estilo en cuanto a la posición de gerente es de escuchar más que actuar. Valoro el "feedback" de cada uno de ustedes y baso mis decisiones en lo que más sea de beneficio para el sitio *después* de considerar sus puntos de vista.  Soy un ser humano como todos ustedes (a excepción de los bots y webcrawlers que nos visitan a diario) y es probable que cometa errores. Espero que cuando eso ocurra puedan recordar que no estoy aquí para ser un dictador tiránico ni nada de eso. Nos hablaremos con respeto y con un espíritu de comunidad y todo saldrá bien.

No pretendo saber ni la mitad de desarrollo de lo que un miembro promedio sabe.  Pero eso no importa porque no estoy aquí para contestar respuestas sobre código sino para ayudar a crecer y a fortalecer nuestra comunidad.  Estoy de nuevo sacudiendo los libros y ejercitando mis habilidades con el código así que, ¡cuenten con preguntas mías también!

### ¿Cuál es la dirección para el sitio?

Esto es fácil: llenar nuestro sitio con los mejores recursos para los desarrolladores de habla hispana.

¿Cómo podemos lograr esto?

1. Preguntando sobre temas de los cuales estamos tratando en nuestros trabajos y proyectos diarios.
2. Preguntando sobre temas actuales y originales.
3. Respondiendo a las preguntas lo mejor que podamos dando crédito allá donde haga falta.
4. No copiando material, intentando publicar material original. El traducir algo existente de alto valor se vale siempre y cuando se dé el crédito debido.
5. Respetando a los demás y ayudando a los que lo necesitan.

Esta comunidad se formará con tiempo.  Vamos a enfrentar problemas que Stack Overflow en inglés nunca tuvo.  Sera nuestra aventura el decidir cómo hacer crecer nuestra comunidad.  No seremos un clon del sitio en inglés.  No intenten formar un gemelo tampoco.  Somos un sitio propio y único porque nuestra cultura e idioma también lo es.

¡Disfruten su estancia aquí! Si necesitan algo, háganmelo saber. Visiten el chat y denme tiempo para responder a sus preguntas y comentarios,pues tengo un montón de cosas que hacer a diario.

Nos vemos en la red. :)

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan, esperemos este sitio sea un éxito, como lo es actualmente StackOverflow!, por la cantidad de usuarios que puede captar y la información seguramente sera un lugar importante para centralizar conocimiento relacionado a tecnologías de información!

Comment: "les prometo que cometeré errores"... ten cuidado de no hacer promesas que no puedas cumplir ;-)

Comment: @Konamiman ya me editaron la publicación por errores de ortografía...aparentemente ya empece con errores :D

Comment: Excelente @JuanM, el objetivo es formar el mejor sitio, vamos a eso!

Comment: ¡Todos alaben a @JuanM, digo, al hipnosapo! ¡Gloria al hipnosapo!

Comment: @JuanM Mi estimado, estamos aquí para echarte la mano. Todos los que estamos participando en la beta privada seguramente estaremos al pendiente de que las cosas marchen bien. En lo personal, quiero que es.SO sea exitoso. Muchas gracias por tu esfuerzo. ¡Todos, a darle!

Comment: @JuanM indudablemente es un sitio que con el simple hecho de existir, ya es éxito :D ¡caminemos al futuro!, ¡felicidades! y gracias por la dedicación y compromiso impreso en este proyecto para lograrlo.

Comment: @JuanM ¡esOS! ¡cumpliendo promesas desde la primera publicación! ¡Bien! :D

Comment: Y que cuando lleguen esos errores sirvan para poder reirnos juntos!

Comment: podriamos  cambiar el titulo del post no? Queda muy poco natural. Podría ser algo como: **Bienvenidos a vuestro sitio**, no?

Comment: @JordiCastilla si usa "vuestro" quedaría orientado a la audiencia española, mejor que sea algo neutro para que no hayan conflictos entre españoles y LatAm

Comment: @JhonAlx pues que se mantenga el su, pero el *este* queda redundante, a eso me referia. Igualmente no entiendo que discriminación es el vuestro...