# Propuesta: sitio tipo Server Fault o Super User en castellano

Tags: discusión, stackexchange, area51

Propongo que exista un lugar para poder realizar este tipo de preguntas:

[¿Cómo consultar cuándo y si un nodo fail-over se ha activado en Azure Traffic Manager?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/401/95)

Actualmente existen usuarios que no consideran que deba existir este tipo de preguntas, ya que no tienen que ver con desarrollo pero sí con configuración de software. Por lo tanto se está pidiendo cerrar la pregunta, pero el problema es que no existe aún el lugar ideal para realizarla en castellano.

Podría ser un sitio similar a [Super User](https://superuser.com/) o [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) de la red Stack Exchange.

Comment: Sería excelente tener un sitio asi

Comment: Actualmente está corriendo una encuesta con esta pregunta [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/encuesta-definici%C3%B3n-de-la-tem%C3%A1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio). La verdad un sitio así no lo veo en el futuro cercano, nada más este sitio tomó 3 años para salir de Area51 y no conozco ninguna variante por idioma de sitios aparte de SO con pt, jp, ru y es.

Comment: Como bien dice @JhonAlx: no contemos con ello.

Comment: @astrojuanlu bueno, qué hacemos con ese tipo de preguntas entonces?

Comment: Desde meta esSO no se puede hacer nada con tu discusión. Me parece que lo tuyo debería ser una propuesta en [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)... Es el lugar donde correspondería que esté... Eso sí, lee muy bien otras propuestas y los resultados, porque las chances de que prospere son muy bajas

Comment: SF en portugués [murió antes mismo](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2543/super-user-em-portugu%C3%AAs-por-que-o-projeto-foi-fechado) de decir `Hello, World`. Hubo bastante drama y rencor, y ya está todo arreglado y superado. Pero la respuesta es exactamente esa: [**no**](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/174/sitio-tipo-serverfault-o-superuser/186#186).

Comment: Elenasys: Por favor agrega al título Propuesta. Esto porque al menos una pregunta también sobre Server Fault fue marcada como duplicada de esta pero la naturaleza de ambas son distintas. La otra preguntaba si se permitirían las preguntas del tipo Server Fault en SOes y esta por lo contrario es una propuesta de un nuevo sitio.

Comment: Claro Rubén, buena idea. Saludos.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Este tipo de preguntas tienen lugar aquí.  Hay que recordar que nuestra organización será diferente a la de [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com) y por lo tanto, vamos a intentar cosas diferentes aquí.

Comment: Me parece fantástico que haya la apertura para probar cosas diferentes. ¿Se permitirán meta-etiquetas? Véase la discusión en [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/encuesta-definici%c3%b3n-de-la-tem%c3%a1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio)

Comment: ¿Cómo ponemos esto en algún lugar donde esté todo el reglamento de la comunidad?

Comment: @JuanK Tenemos el centro de ayuda pero también existe un lugar donde puedo insertar texto (arriba de los primeros artículos del centro de ayuda).  Se puede poner un resumen ahi.

Comment: @JuanM Esto no se cumple ...

Comment: estoy proponiendo cambios en la pagina de ayuda on-topic para que esto se cumpla: [Propuesta de Cambio a la Pagina de Ayuda: ¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí? / on-topic](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5378/propuesta-de-cambio-a-la-pagina-de-ayuda-sobre-qu%c3%a9-temas-puedo-preguntar-aqu%c3%ad)

Answer (score 9):

ACTUALIZACIÓN: Veáse la [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/211/65) de [Juan M](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m)

## Respuesta corta

Actualmente no se están admitiendo propuestas para nuevos sitios en SE en idiomas distintos al inglés. Por lo pronto, leer detenidamente [¡Bienvenidos a este su sitio!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146/65) por [Juan M](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m) para tener mayor claridad -o ampliar las dudas - de lo que se puede o no preguntar y/o proponer en Stack Overflow en español en estos momentos.

## Explicación

Las propuestas para nuevos sitios en la red de Stack Exchange deben realizarse en [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). Lamentablemente Stack Overflow (la compañía) no cuenta con los recursos suficientes para dar respuesta en un tiempo razonable así que para no crear expectativas han decidido cerrar todas las propuestas que que hubiesen tenido "luz verde". Considero que hemos sido afortunados de que al momento que tomó esa decisión la propuesta de Stack Overflow en español ya estaba "más allá que pa'ca"

## Referencias

- [respuesta](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20138/133145)
  por [Tim
  Post](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/202/tim-post) a
  [Any news about the non-english SE site
  proposals?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19351/133145),
  21 de marzo de 2015
- [Internationalization 'State of the Stack' - SE 2.0 Sites
  edition](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-se-2-0-sites-edition)
  por [Tim
  Post](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/202/tim-post), 17
  de junio de 2015

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Ruben, tienes razón hay que valorar por el momento tener al menos SO en español. +1.

Answer (score 2):

¿Esto sigue en el mismo estado? Cada vez llegan más preguntas del tipo `cómo enruto mi módem ddwrt para que los DNS se conecten con la VLAN blablablá` o `cómo configuro el driver del winmodem en Kali Linux cuando tengo esta tarjeta de red entregada por los seres del mundo interior`, que claramente no van en SO de acuerdo a las normas estándar.

(perdón por revivir una pregunta con respuesta aceptada)

Comment: Creo que en todo caso deberías publicarlo como una nueva pregunta... Y te recomiendo separar bien específico el alcance, ya que las del tipo "SuperUser"por lo general están todos en contra, las del tipo "ServerFault" creo que dependen del contexto y son bastante mejor recibidas cuando tienen algo relacionado a programación (incluyendo entorno de programación). Estas son otras 2 preguntas que me parecieron relevantes: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/193460 y https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4278/193460, pero vas a encontrar muchas más bajo [meta-tag:temática]

Comment: @Pollo es que ha llegado de todo. Hoy vi una de redes, el fin de semana hubo unas de linux y de cómo publicar un servidor local. Entonces, no sé hasta dónde aguante serverFault (porque ahí fijo no cabe nada de configuraciones de sistemas operativos y manejo básico de redes o configuración de equipos comunes en entornos locales)

Comment: como lo decía, para que lo que aquí se pacto y se marco como respuesta se cumpla en el sitio estoy solicitando un cambio en la pagina de ayuda on-topic: [Propuesta de Cambio a la Pagina de Ayuda: ¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí? / on-topic](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5378/propuesta-de-cambio-a-la-pagina-de-ayuda-sobre-qu%c3%a9-temas-puedo-preguntar-aqu%c3%ad)