# Propongo si se puede crear un sitio para DDD (Domain Driven Design)

Tags: característica-nueva, meta

Lo que comento no es una pregunta, mas es una solicitud de poder crear un sitio sobre DDD (Domain Driven Design) donde se pueda hablar, compartir de nuestras experiencias de trabajo usando este patrón de arquitectura. Los foros que he encontrado son en ingles y son muy pocos.

Comment: Quizá esto es más una petición para [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MiquelColl si, el problema es que no se ingles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sin quitar el hecho de que puedes proponer la creación de un sitio nuevo específico para DDD, no olvides que siempre que cumplas con las reglas de este sitio es perfectamente válido

**utilizar StackOverflow en Español para realizar tus preguntas y respuestas de DDD**

o cualquier otra temática relacionada con el desarrollo de software.

Esto, siempre que:

- La pregunta pueda responderse
- La respuesta no esté basada en opiniones
- Etcétera, para más información sobre lo que puedes preguntar aquí visita: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

A diferencia de los viejos sitios de foros, en StackOverflow en español no hace falta *proponer* la creación de nuevos *sub foros*. Este proceso es manejado directamente por la comunidad. No hace falta más que plantear una primera pregunta con una nueva **[etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)** para crear todo lo que en otro sitio sería visto como un sub-foro.

Además, puedes realizar tu propia promoción para atraer expertos que respondan y novatos que pregunten, que al final, son el alma de la fiesta en SO (y que puede servirte como ejercicio si decides plantear un nuevo sitio en area51).

Answer (score 3):

## Respuesta corta

La forma de proponer nuevos sitios en Stack Exchange es publicar una propuesta **en inglés** en [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), sin embargo debido a la situación actual, como comunidad por el momento deberíamos enfocarnos en consolidar Stack Overflow en Español.

## Explicación

"Actualmente" las propuestas de sitios en idiomas diferentes al inglés están siendo rechazadas. Esto es provisional mientras el equipo de Stack Exchange consolida sus operaciones en relación a los sitios actuales que no son en inglés.

Una alternativa es revisar si la temática es de interés para el público al que está dirigido Stack Overflow en español, pues lo que está dentro/fuera de tema de este sitio es definido por la propia comunidad.

## Referencias

- [Internationalization 'State of the Stack' - SE 2.0 Sites edition](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20988/133145)

## Preguntas relacionadas

- [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%C3%B3n-de-la-tem%C3%A1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio/344#344)
- [Propuesta, sitio tipo: "ServerFault" o "SuperUser"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/174/propuesta-sitio-tipo-serverfault-o-superuser/186#186)

Comment: Si no fuera porque estamos en Beta, sería bueno crear sitios en español para todos, Blender, Inteligencia Artificial (aunque ese también está en beta), ServerFault.

Answer (score -1):

## Y aquí está

- [ddd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ddd)

Que fue creado con la siguiente pregunta
  - [ASP.NET MVC arquitectura DDD(Domain Driven Design)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41889/asp-net-mvc-arquitectura-ddddomain-driven-design)

Varios meses después, sigue siendo la única pregunta con ddd como etiqueta.

Comment: Perdón pero hoy mi creatividad está en cero

Comment: Sin ánimo de entrar en debates, y solo para entender mejor como funciona o debería funcionar Stackoverflow, ¿cómo se aplica lo que dice @jachguate respecto a "... La respuesta no esté basada en opiniones..." en el post que cita @ruben? Temas por el estilo hay montones, donde las respuestas dependen de la percepción/visión de quien responde. A mi me han cerrado varias preguntas justo por ser susceptibles a controversia.

Comment: @CamiloBernal: El espacio y opciones en comentarios es muy breve como para darle un seguimiento y respuesta apropiada a tu comentario. Menciono esto porque no me queda claro 1) si interpretaste correctamente  esta respuesta, la cual por cierto estaba pensando eliminar, 2) si quieres saber cómo funciona la creación de etiquetas, 3) quieres saber como funcionan la moderación, 4) si preguntas porque quieres crear un sitio ó sub-sitio, etc. 5) Si quieres saber por qué existen preguntas basadas en opiniones, 6) si quieres saber qué hacer cuando encuentras una pregunta basada en opiniones

Comment: básicamente mi comentario está orientado a que entiendo que por las politicas de StackOverflow no deberíamos tener preguntas cuyas respuestas estén basadas en opiniones, pero aún así las continúo viendo (el caso de la pregunta citada es solo un ejemplo). Entonces, para responder tu preguntas: la 3, la 5 y la 6 de tu enumeración es lo que me llevó a realizar el comentario anterior.

Comment: @CamiloBernal: El formato de comentarios no facilita llevar discusiones ni las respuestas amplias, lo más apropiado es que publiques una o varias preguntas, de todas va respuestas abreviadas. Sobre 3) la moderación empieza por la propia comunidad y algunas acciones las llevan los "moderadores diamantados" los cuales próximamente serán electos. Sobre 5) algunas preguntas están siendo "toleradas" mientras que otras podrían haber sido ignoradas por tratarse de una temática que no tiene participantes, sobre 6) reporta la pregunta o vótala para cerrar. En caso de duda publica una pregunta en [meta]