# ¡Conozcan a nuestro primer moderador: Konamiman!

Tags: discusión, moderadores

Ya que tenemos nuestro sitio activo, es importante escoger a unos pocos miembros de nuestra comunidad para que nos apoyen en mantener el alto nivel de funcionamiento que deseamos.   Dichos miembros se nombran como moderadores y se les otorga herramientas para poder facilitar el orden del sitio.  Los sitios beta (como el nuestro) necesitan de este tipo de personas para prestar otro par de ojos durante el día y para ayudar a los miembros a mejorar sus experiencias con Stack Overflow en español.

Le pedí a mi nuevo compañero de equipo que nos proporcionara un relato corto sobre su experiencia, su persona, y sus intereses para poder conocerlo mejor.  Aquí, les presento a nuestro primer moderador: **[Konamiman](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/23/konamiman)**

[image: Konamiman]

> ### ¿Quién es Konamiman?
>
> Esta historia comienza en las navidades de 1985, cuando un chavalín de
> once años llamado Néstor Soriano y natural de [Palma de
> Mallorca](https://www.google.es/search?q=palma+de+mallorca&tbm=isch)
> recibió como regalo de navidad un flamante ejemplar de tecnología
> japonesa llamado [Canon
> V-20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_V-20). La vida del susodicho
> cambió por completo en cuanto descubrió que aquella extraña máquina
> obedecería todas sus órdenes siempre que le fueran comunicadas en un
> extraño lenguaje de conjuros llamado
> [BASIC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC).
>
> El tiempo pasó y cuando la popularidad del estándar
> [MSX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSX) se fue desvaneciendo a medida
> que los ordenadores de 8 bits se iban quedando obsoletos, nuestro
> héroe se unió a la resistencia, formada por otros locos que se
> dedicaban a realizar desarrollos de software y hardware para la
> susodicha plataforma. Suya es [la pila TCP/IP desarrollada
> íntegramente en ensamblador de
> Z80](http://konamiman.com/msx/msx-s.html#inl2) ([charla al
> respecto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJomQNEgbww)) o [el sistema
> operativo Nextor](http://konamiman.com/msx/msx-s.html#nextor), por
> poner un par de ejemplos.
>
> El nombre de guerra Konamiman se debe a la afición de nuestro
> protagonista por los videojuegos que Konami lanzó en los años 80 para
> el estándar MSX, en especial la saga
> [Gradius](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradius).
>
> ### Y un poco más en serio...
>
> Dejando un poco de lado la locura del MSX, desde hace ya trece años me
> gano la vida programando en C#, habiendo hecho un poco de todo
> (Winforms, Silverlight, WPF, .NET Compact Framework, .NET Micro
> Framework, ASP.NET) y estando ahora más bien centrado en ASP.NET MVC y
> WebAPI (y JavaScript, claro, lenguaje del que nadie se libra hoy en
> día) :-) Aparte de [mi web
> personal](http://www.konamiman.com/msx/msx-s.html) tengo [un par de
> cosas chulas publicadas en
> Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/konamiman).
>
> [Llevo en Stack
> Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4574/konamiman?tab=profile)
> desde que se lanzó la beta privada allá por 2008. En cuanto al
> proyecto de Stack Overflow en español, me enrolé a través de Area51 un
> poco tarde (por despiste, no hay más misterio) pero he tratado de
> contribuir en lo posible con traducciones, correcciones, contenido en
> el propio sitio, y en general todo lo que ha estado en mi mano para
> aliviar la carga de trabajo de [nuestro bienamado
> líder](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m?tab=profile).
>
> Supone un gran honor para mí haberme convertido en el primer moderador
> del sitio y no os preocupéis, que como si de una vulgar campaña
> electoral se tratara, [si otros pueden prometer
> errores](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146/23), ¡yo puedo
> prometer el doble! Espero poder ver cómo entre todos formamos una
> comunidad potente que se convierta en referente mundial de la
> comunidad de programadores hispanohablantes (arcoiris, arpas y
> unicornios de fondo) y lo intentaré hacer lo mejor que pueda a pesar
> de que nunca he moderado nada (creo que ni mi propia casa).
>
> Y ahora, por el poder que me ha sido concedido, os conmino a todos a
> preguntar, a responder y a llevaros bien.

Por favor ayudenme a darle una gran bienvenida a Konamiman, ¡nuestro primer moderador!

Comment: bienvenido @Konamiman

Comment: felicitaciones @Konamiman

Comment: @Konamiman Muy merecido !! que bueno contar contigo

Comment: Felicitaciones @Konamiman

Comment: Bienvenido, gracias por prestarte a ayudarnos!

Comment: Bienvenido @Konamiman!

Comment: ¡Bienvenido! Hará una buena labor.

Comment: ¿MSX? ¿Konami? Uf, nos va a moderar un friki de cuidado... ¡que no nos pase nada!

Comment: @Konamiman ¡Que chingón! ¡Felicidades!

Comment: ¡Felicidades @Konamiman! :)

Comment: これから、お世話になります, no ya en serio agradecemos de antemano tu apoyo.

Comment: @MatthewJoelRodríguezLlanos どうもありがとうございました!

Comment: Están seguros seguros segurísimos de lo que han hecho? He sufrido a este señor durante meses y os garantizo que lo hará lo mejor posible y luego no os lo podréis quitar de encima, ni queriendo. Enhorabuena Nextor, ya te dije yo que ibas a llegar lejos ;)

Comment: @Konamiman ¡Muchas felicidades y mucho éxito!

Comment: Felicidades, pero fue elegido democráticamente?, creo que me perdí de las elecciones! =(, felicidades nuevamente =).

Comment: @Konamiman +1 hey ya me caíste muy bien por esa corbata!, desearía tener una igual!

Comment: @Elenasys En los sitios beta los moderadores temporales (que es lo que soy) son elegidos "a dedo" por el personal de SE (JuanM en este caso). Cuando salgamos de beta se convocarán elecciones. La corbata es de papel y la hizo uno de mis hijos.

Comment: Bienvenido @Konamiman, suerte y paciencia.

Comment: Felicidades @Konamiman!!

Answer (score 5):

Lo que más me impresionó de todo es haber encontrado un usuario activo de BitBucket :)

¡Felicitaciones, y gracias por el esfuerzo!

<kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: Uso Bitbucket simplemenre porque yo soy más de Mercurial que de Git. :-)