# Celebración para la graduación del sitio en España

Tags: discusión, encuentros-locales, graduación

Estoy planeando la celebración de nuestra graduación en España pero necesito saber qué ciudad funcionará mejor - Madrid o Barcelona. La fecha cae en la semana de mayo 22-28.

Por favor contesten con la ciudad en donde les es más fácil asistir.  Votaremos por la mejor sacaré de allí el lugar donde tendremos nuestra celebración.

¡A votar!

<s>La votación terminará el 3 de mayo.</s>

La ciudad en donde tendremos nuestra celebración será  - ¡Madrid!

---

## Acualización:

La celebración en España ocurrirá en Madrid el 25 de mayo. Gracias a la amistad que tenemos con [IronHack](https://www.ironhack.com/es), tendremos el evento en sus oficinas....y vaya, ¡que oficinas!  Tuve la oportunidad de ver el espacio que ocupan por medios virtuales, y como dicen por ahí, esta bien chulo el lugar. Habrán charlas dadas por nuestro querido [Konamiman](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276/conozcan-a-nuestro-primer-moderador-konamiman), alumnus de IronHack, y también por mi.

Nos fascinaría verlos el 25 de mayo. El evento es gratis y no se requiere nada para asistir.  Tendremos comida y bebida y la oportunidad de conocernos en persona!

Para apuntarse, favor de **[hacerlo aquí por EventBrite](https://www.eventbrite.com/e/stack-overflow-presenta-su-arranque-en-espana-en-el-nuevo-campus-de-ironhack-tickets-34499150889)**. Las direcciones y la agenda se puede encontrar ahí. Si tienen preguntas o comentarios, favor de hacerlas aquí.

¡Nos vemos pronto!

Estamos ya en Madrid para celebrar nuestra graduación.  ¡El espacio está hermoso al igual que la gente! Al ver el horario, habíamos puesto que tendríamos un livestream pero no será posible. Lamento el no poder hacerlo, pero tomaremos fotos y las compartimos aquí.

**Fotos del evento:**

[image: Oficinas de IronHack Madrid]
[image: Oficinas 2]
[image: Pablo, JuanM, Konamiman]
[image: Presentación1]
[image: Presentación2]
[image: Charla]
[image: Konamiman[![][6]]
[image: Konamiman_2]
[image: Konamiman_3]
[image: Attendees]
[image: Attendees_2]
[image: Panelists]

Comment: ¿Entonces 22-28 de mayo es la fecha de graduación?

Comment: ¿No hay fecha para América del Sur?

Comment: Sea el lugar que sea el elegido, será de ayuda notificarlo con tiempo y que sea en fin de semana para que los que optaron por la otra opción puedan intentar desplazarse.

Comment: @Shaz lamentablemente no habrá fecha para América de Sur...pero, se organiza un Meetup en [Buenos Aires para el cuatro de mayo](https://www.meetup.com/StackOverflow-en-Espanol-Buenos-Aires/events/239465138/).

Comment: en qué consistirá la celebración ?

Comment: @lois6b comida, bebida, compañerismo :)

Comment: hahaha @JuanM me tuviste con "comida" <3

Comment: @lois6b a todos.! forever gorditos! <3 :D

Comment: Llega a ser a principios de mayo y voto por Madrid, que me voy unos días , pero el desplazamiento me queda muy, muy lejos. A mi también con la comida <3 :DDD

Comment: Vaya, parece ser que no podré asistir por motivos de viajes ... os deseo a todos los participantes una gran celebración ^^

Comment: ya se sabe que día será?

Comment: Yo me enfado y no respiro.

Comment: Detalles del evento [Celebración para la graduación del sitio en España](https://www.eventbrite.com/e/stack-overflow-presenta-su-arranque-en-espana-en-el-nuevo-campus-de-ironhack-tickets-34499150889).

Comment: @wchiquito gracias por compartir los detalles. Qué pena que sea en jueves, siendo entre semana los que estamos en otras ciudades no podremos asistir.

Comment: @fedorqui Se que no es lo ideal para todos pero es la fecha en que se pudo organizar todo.  Si pudiera, les pagaría a todos el boleto para venir y su hotel.  :(

Comment: Exacto @fedorqui, siendo entre semana creo que va a quedar un poco deslucido

Comment: @JuanM: ¿Hay posibilidad de live streaming del evento?, sería una alternativa para quienes no podemos estar físicamente.

Comment: ¿Alguien podría imprimir mi avatar y dejarlo sobre una mesa? Para sentir como que estoy allí... :'(

Comment: Lástima, justo estuve en Madrid la semana pasada

Comment: ¡Ojalá sea un éxito! Me apena que no se haya facilitado que el resto de gente podamos estar presentes, ya sea físicamente (para México sí se cambió a viernes, aquí se pidió y no se hizo) o virtualmente (al no haber emisión en directo).

Comment: Espero que les haya ido muy bien en su celebración :) Ojala haya video ;)

Comment: ¿Y las fotos? ¿No hay fotos?

Comment: Que pena no haber podido asistir y haberme enterado tarde de la graduación del sitio :'(. Hubiera estado muy bien el poder haber ido :P

Answer (score 14):

Podría asistir fácilmente a una celebración en **Madrid**.

Comment: Sabéis que [Madrid no tiene playa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hWCZK0Hf0A) ¿verdad?.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster sí, pero buenas noticias... tiene un AVE estupendo para poder venir desde Barcelona en unas tres horas de nada :D

Comment: Vale un pastón >_<

Comment: Jajaja ya tenía que salir lo de la playa :P

Comment: @astrojuanlu estaba en bandeja ;P

Comment: Valencia tiene playa y AVE ajjajaaja

Answer (score 4):

Podría asistir fácilmente a una celebración en **Barcelona**.

Comment: ¡Aúpa Barcelona! (*por favor*) :(