# Cómo la temática del sitio principal y de Meta podría ser útil para iniciar a un adolescente en la programación

Tags: discusión, temática

Tengo un hijo de 15 y estoy pensando en iniciarle en la programación, ya sea con materiales en la web, en alguna academia (en Madrid) o las dos cosas. Estoy abierto a todos los consejos, pero claro me gustaría saber en primer lugar si existe algún sitio en Stack Exchange donde se traten estas temáticas.

Comment: Creo sinceramente que el mejor lugar para esta pregunta es [parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No lo conocía. Pero veo en un sitio en inglés por lo que supongo que de Madrid poco me podrán aconsejar. Gracias igualmente

Comment: No podrán ayudarte sobre Madrid (o si, tal vez haya algún usuario Madrileño) pero tu problema, a mi entender, es que quieres motivar a tu hijo y eso es un problema común en el mundo entero. Tal vez te den ideas diferentes e igual de válidas sobre motivación sin que éstas tengan que ver con programación.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster es ahora ParentingMaster :P

Comment: Estimado Gonzalo, te sugiero editar el título, específicamente quitar lo de formación porque es un tema delicado ya que abarca mucho más que trata de aprender técnicas, abarca filosofía (ética, moral, economía, etc.), y otras cosas que podría causar controversias para las cuales algunos dudamos que estemos preparados como comunidad. En algunos países esto es más delicado que en otros y siendo este un sitio prácticamente global pues mas vale proceder con pies de plomo cuando están involucrados menores de edad.

Comment: Lo anterior viene a colación a raíz de unos comentarios a mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta a la [revisión 3](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2159/3)

Me parece que has adecuado bien la pregunta para que quede dentro de la temática de Meta.

En https://stackexchange.com/sites puedes consultar la lista completa de sitios de toda la red. Cabe señalar que actualmente sólo hay un sitio en español el cual es https://es.stackoverflow.com (SOes) y que por un tiempo no habrá más sitios en español.

En SOes pueden realizar **preguntas sobre programación y otros temas relacionados**. Cabe señalar que este sitio sigue un modelo similar a la Stack Overflow en inglés pero hay cosas que la comunidad de este sitio ha determinado que **sean distintas** como la temática del sitio. Para consultar sobre lo que la comunidad opina que debe incluirse o no, consulten [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/65).

Las preguntas se catalogan mediante **etiquetas** las cuales tienen un **wiki** en el que la comunidad ha incluido indicaciones de cómo usar la etiqueta en cuestión y en algunas de ellas se encuentran **recursos** que pueden ser de utilidad para aprender. Vale la pena que las revisen antes de realizar una pregunta.

Existen **otros sitios** que les podrían ser de utilidad. A continuación les comparto un par:

Mucha de la documentación y materiales disponibles sobre programación primero se publican en inglés, así que vale la pena dedicar tiempo a aprender este idioma y para ello les podría servir [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Programación es una tarea de un campo más amplio llamado Ciencias Computacionales. Stack Exchange tiene un sitio para estudiantes de esta disciplina: [Computer Sciences](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

## Respuesta a la [revisión 1](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2159/1)

La pregunta es demasiado amplia y fuera de tema. La etiqueta discusión existe para tratar temas sobre el funcionamiento del sitio principal, su contenido y su comunidad. También se puede preguntar sobre la red de Stack Exchange.

Lo que podrías hacer es consultar si existe un sitio en [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) donde se trate la temática sobre la cómo ser buenos padres, sobre formación de adolescentes  o editarla para hacerla más específica y dentro de tema pore ejemplo,podrías preguntar cómo la temática del el sitio principal y este mismo podría ser de utilidad para la formación de un adolescente. También podrías preguntar sobre eventos de Stack Overflow y su comunidad. Por cierto, recientemente se realizó la [Celebración para la graduación del sitio en España](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1844/65).

Como ya tienes más de 20 puntos de reputación, un recurso que podrías aprovechar para conversar con miembros de la comunidad es el chat del sitio.

Comment: Más allá de que creo que esta pregunta no está dentro del alcance del sitio, creo que no conviene aconsejar a un padre sobre la educación de su hijo. Por lo menos no acá. SOes no es un sitio donde haya profesionales que puedan responder a preguntas sobre la crianza de un hijo, y si bien sé que la intención es ayudar, también hay que considerar posibles repercusiones que un consejo de este estilo puede tener si el resultado no es positivo.

Comment: Como siempre muy interesante tu punto de vista Mariano. Como verás no estoy dando consejo ni haciendo juicios de valor sobre  las decisiones que como padre podría tomar, tan sólo le estoy facilitando información sobre algunos sitios de SE afines a la temática de programación y que los wikis de etiqueta podría tener información útil. No mencionando nada sobre moral, ética, disciplina, planeación de vida, orientación vocacional, etc.

Comment: Me quedó claro al leerlo, jamás dudé de tu intención ni de lo que respondiste. Sólo me preocupa qué puede pasar con una publicación de este estilo si en un futuro "*algo se complica*". Creo que en SOes no estamos capacitados para dar respuesta a estas cosas (y el autor jamás siguió la recomendación de preguntar en [parenting.se]).

Comment: Me parece que con una edición del título se solucionaría el problema pero no la hago porque cambiaría el sentido original del autor. Me parece que lo que procede es solicitarle el cambio.

Comment: Espero que con esta modificación a la redacción del título se disipen las cautelas. No he preguntado en Parenting porque parte del objetivo de mi pregunta es saber dónde puedo llevarle en Madrid, pero sobretodo por falta de tiempo. Acabo de reeditar el título pero por desgracia hasta mañana no podré poner en práctica vuestras sugencias. Gracias

Comment: Un amigo me ha convencido de que una buena opción es que el chaval empiece con python, y además me ha aconsejado una academia prestigiosa y que está cerca de casa. De todos modos me guardo los enlaces que habéis pegado aquí, porque seguro que me surgirán futuras consultas y ya sabré dónde dirigirlas sin hacer perder tiempo a nadie. Muchas gracias a todos