# ¿Quiénes forman el Community Team? ¿Qué hacen?

Tags: soporte, faq, stackexchange, moderadores

> Esta es una traducción de [Who are the Community Team, and what do they do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do)

¿Quiénes integran el Community Team, también conocido como Community Managers o CMs? ¿Cuál es su función?

¿Cuál es su relación con el [usuario Community](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Esta es una traducción de la respuesta aceptada en [Who are the Community Team, and what do they do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/209901)
> Corrige todo aquello que veas que no es correcto o necesite mejora.

### ¿Quiénes integran el Community Team?

#### [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)

[image: Robert Cartaino's network flair]

#### [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9)

[image: The network flair of Shog9]

#### [hairboat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165581/hairboat)

[image: Network flair for hairboat]

#### [Grace Note](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/146126/grace-note)

[image: Network flair for Grace]

#### [Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post)

[image: Network flair for Tim Post]

#### [Jon Ericson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1438/jon-ericson)

[image: Network flair for Jon]

#### [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/274323/nicolas-chabanovsky)

[image: Network flair for Nicolas]

#### [Juan M](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m)

[image: Network flair for Juan M]

#### [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson)

[image: Network flair for animuson]

#### [JNat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/208518/jnat)

[image: Network flair for JNat]

#### [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija)

[image: Network flair for Catija]

#### [Cesar M](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/508266/cesar-m)

[image: Network flair for Cesar M]

### ¿Qué hacen?

Ellos te ayudan. No, en serio.

Revisan que los sitios propuestos en [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), analizando, mostrando sus dudas, cerrando, eliminando y preparando todo para que sean lanzados cuando sea necesario.

Moderan los sitios acabados de lanzar, contestan preguntas e intentan las lecciones aprendidas en sitios anteriores. Ellos eligen los moderadores [Pro Tem](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) y les traspasan el sitio a estos.

Son el ombligo de los administradores de Stack Exchange, siempre expectantes.

Están pendientes de todo tipo de sitios Meta, responden preguntas, procesan o escalan peticiones y ayudan en el uso de las herramientas del sitio.

A veces contestan correos electrónicos.

Revisan las acciones de los moderadores, dan consejo, resuelven disputas.

A veces incluso duermen. Eso sí, con un ojo abierto, como los pájaros.

### ¿Son lo mismo que el usuario Comunidad?

No, no lo son. Ese es un [usuario especial](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidad).

Comment: Traducción bastante libre, me cargué partes humorísticas que no aplicaban aquí. Además, la lista de moderadores puede quedar obsoleta, será cuestión de ir comparando con la publicación original.

Comment: Relacionado: [Bienvenidos a este su sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/146/bienvenidos-a-este-su-sitio) (incluye la sección "¿Quén es Juan M?")

Comment: Has puesto el link de Juan M así porque así es como aparece en la pregunta original en inglés. Y no está mal. Pero yo creo que sería más útil poner el link a su cuenta en el meta español: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m

Comment: Yo, como mi ombligo... siempre expectante de nuevas traducciones de FAQs.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos ¡bien visto! Actualizado. En todos estos FAQ-proposed, siéntete libre de editar tú mismo si ves mejoras.

Comment: @fedorqui una pregunta, justo al final de la respuesta, en el link *[usuario especial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=community+user)* redirecciona a la búsqueda de Community User, considero que ideal sería que haga una redirección al usuario Comunidad de SOes, o en su caso, redireccionar a la traducción de [esta pregunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user). A lo mejor me perdí de algo y es correcto que redireccione justo a la búsqueda :)

Comment: @Flxtr en la publicación original había ese enlace a la búsqueda de "community user", pues genera muchas preguntas en Meta SE. Pero sí, es confuso y no aporta nada, así que he puesto un enlace a tal usuario en este sitio. ¡Gracias! Esto cada vez es menos una traducción y más un _fork_ :)

Comment: ¡Gracias @Juan por corregir las imágenes!

Comment: esto ha cambiado mucho últimamente https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/99341/revisions que corrija quien quiera