# ¿Qué podemos hacer como comunidad ante un usuario que está provocando daño?

Tags: discusión, moderación, usuarios

Ayer el sitio tuvo un rato de cierto malestar ante un usuario que se puso a comentar a diestro y siniestro... bastante siniestramente.

La comunidad intentó reaccionar rápido usando reportes, pero después votando negativamente sus publicaciones. Al haber cierta sensación de falta de moderación, toledano [explica lo que se hizo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1939/83):

> Lo que hizo Tato Broh no cae en lo que podemos llamar un comportamiento normal. Sí entiendo correctamente al votar en negativo, perdió el privilegio de seguir comentando

La lógica utilizada, pues, fue la de hacerle perder los [50 puntos que permiten comentar en todas partes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Sin embargo esto entra en contradicción con el hecho de que siempre intentamos votar por contenido, no por personas.

Entonces la duda razonable que surge es: ¿Qué podemos hacer como comunidad ante un caso de usuario que está haciendo daño ahora mismo? ¿Cómo podemos pararlo?

<sub>La respuesta es wiki para intentar que, entre todos, encontremos los mejores recursos que redunden en el beneficio de la comunidad. Añadí alguna, pero no dudes en modificar para añadir o eliminar.</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Antes de nada, es bueno recordar que todas las publicaciones tienen un historial de revisiones. Por tanto, si el usuario está destruyendo contenido será trivial (aunque cansado) recuperarlo.

---

Otro hecho importante a tener en cuenta es lo que dicen en inglés *don't feed the trolls!*, es decir, **¡no alimentemos a los trolls!** Si alguien está siendo provocativo, no hay nada que le aliente más que ver cómo nos lo tomamos en serio.

---

Si detectamos cualquier cosa perniciosa, ¡reportemos! Tal y como indica [¿Qué es un reporte?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts):

> Los reportes son una forma de llamar la atención de la comunidad sobre algún contenido inapropiado.

Y luego:

> Si pasa algo en nuestro sitio que te hace sentir incómodo o que, en tu opinión, claramente no pertenece aquí, por favor, ¡reporta y llama nuestra atención!

Sigue diciendo:

> *¿Qué pasa cuando reporto algo como spam o abusivo?*
>
> Los reportes de spam y abusivos están diseñados para eliminar automáticamente las publicaciones realmente perjudiciales a través de la colaboración de la comunidad.
>
> - 3 reportes - la publicación es quitada de la página frontal.
> - 6 reportes - la publicación es bloqueada, borrada, y el propietario pierde 100 puntos de reputación.

Por tanto, en el caso que haya [una respuesta que era claramente abusiva](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/68887/83) puede ser suficiente reportarla como tal para hacerle perder 100 puntos y, por ende, que pireda la capacidad de comentar.

Si no existe ninguna publicación de ese tipo, obviamente no debemos marcar como tal a otra que sea buena, claro está :)

---

En cuanto a los comentarios, volvamos a lo dicho antes: pueden ser molestos, pero para un moderador será un momentito eliminarlos. Eso sí, si nos parecen provocativos, fuera de lugar o directamente abusivos, reportémolos.

> *¿Qué pasa cuando reporto un comentario?*
>
> Además de traer el comentario a la atención de los moderadores, un número suficiente de reportes en un solo comentario hará que se borre automáticamente. El número de indicadores necesarios para su eliminación varía en función del número de votos en el comentario, así como el contenido del comentario en sí.

La fórmula viene explicada en [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/209901) (pendiente de traducir al [FAQ de este sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/83)).

> Comments that are flagged by multiple users are deleted automatically.  The number of flags needed is [based on the comment's score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138168/reduce-the-threshold-for-comment-deletion-with-flags?lq=1#comment388189_138168).  It currently takes "`3 + (Score / 3)`" flags to delete a comment.

Esto es:

> Los comentarios que son reportados por múltiples usuarios se eliminan automáticamente. El número de reportes necesarios [está basado en la puntuación del comentario](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138168/reduce-the-threshold-for-comment-deletion-with-flags?lq=1#comment388189_138168).  Actualmente son necesarios "`3 + (Puntuación / 3)`" reportes para eliminar un comentario.

Por tanto, suponiendo un comentario con puntuación 0, con `3 + 0/3 = 3` reportes es suficiente para que se elimine.

---

En casos de extrema gravedad, si no hay ningún moderador del sitio disponible puede ser necesario escalar el caso a los Community Manager del Stack Exchange. Los tenemos listados en [¿Quiénes forman el Community Team? ¿Qué hacen?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1671/83). Siempre hay alguno en el chat.

Comment: muy bueno eso de los seis reportes no lo sabia. Saludos

Comment: El tema es qué pasa cuando ni un moderador ni un CM toman las medidas necesarias?. Esta comunidad es demasiado pequeña para poder seguir el juego de reportear cada comentario que hace un usuario destinado a destruir valor en el sitio. En estos casos, qué se puede hacer?

Comment: @Lamak Tienes varias opciones. 1.- La paciencia. 2.- Puedes escalar un nivel más. Envíale un e-mail al Director de CMs si piensas que el CM no hace su trabajo bien. [Robert Cartaino](http://stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino). 3.- Usa el enlace de [contacto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact), está en todas las páginas. 4.- Pensártelo otra vez, ¿Los insultos abundantes son un caso de extrema gravedad?. *Los palos y las piedras pueden romper mis huesos, pero las palabras nunca lograrán herirme*. Grave sería publicar claves bancarias por ejemplo, eso sí requiere mucha rapidez.

Comment: Lo que no es una buena opción es incumplir las normas del sitio. Por ejemplo votando negativo para quitar a alguien el privilegio de comentar.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos no voté negativo en sus posts con este objetivo. Tampoco creo que el CM no haga su trabajo bien. De la misma forma, no creo que la paciencia sea la solución, porque afecta fuertemente el sitio, no es un tema personal