# Qué hacer con aparente flood

Tags: discusión

Me he topado con un usuario que publica respuestas sin sentido, en un intento (fallido) para subir reputación en SOes. He reportado las respuestas pertinentes, pero no sé si debería hacerse más.

El usuario es: [silvida-plancarte](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/59111/silvia-plancarte)

Si entran al perfil de dicho usuario, verán que todas sus respuestas (100%) son comentarios (sin sentido). En otras comunidades, normalmente contactaría directamente con la persona enviándole un mensaje indicando que hace mal, no obstante,SOEs no es un foro, así que quisiera saber qué hacer en estos casos.

Comment: Lo de que es _un intento (fallido) para subir reputación en SOes_ no lo podemos saber. Lo que está claro es que no son respuestas y que lo que toca es reportarlas, votarlas negativamente y votar por borrarlas. Alguna ya se ha eliminado así.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Qué podemos hacer como comunidad ante un usuario que está provocando daño?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1940/qu%c3%a9-podemos-hacer-como-comunidad-ante-un-usuario-que-est%c3%a1-provocando-da%c3%b1o)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lo básico es votar y reportar.

A través de los votos y reportes  ayudamos a que los filtros automáticos del sistema entren en efecto. Por ejemplo, los usuarios que repetidamente hacen publicaciones de malas respuesta serán bloqueados por el sistema para realizar nuevas respuestas. Más detalles en [¿Por qué ya no se aceptan respuestas desde mi cuenta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans)

Answer (score 6):

**Debes reportarlo.**

<strike>Sus respuestas se eliminaran automáticamente si tienen suficientes votos negativos</strike>. Los únicos que pueden banear usuarios son los moderadores. Nosotros como comunidad podemos reportar las publicaciones, votarlas negativas <strike>para que se eliminen automáticamente</strike> y nada mas.

No creo que igual su cometido sea subir reputación, ya que sus respuestas carecen totalmente de algún sentido.

Como nota al margen, reporte para eliminación la mayoría de sus publicaciones, y también reporte directamente a un moderador una de las publicaciones por si alguno de ellos entraba, diciéndoles cual era el problema con el usuario. No es el método recomendado (se que esta mal) pero estaba spameando demasiado en un momento.

Comment: Buena respuesta. De todos modos, lo de _Sus respuestas se eliminaran automáticamente si tienen suficientes votos negativos_ no es cierto. Se eliminan en ciertos casos: si distintos usuarios con bastante reputación votan para eliminarla o si así se decide en una cola de revisión; en ningún caso los votos negativos por sí solos eliminan una respuesta.