# Diccionario de términos técnicos en castellano

Tags: discusión, traducciones, idioma-español, glosario

Al hilo de [Traduciendo el sitio... Esta vez, con más control sobre el proceso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3378/83), ha surgido otra vez el debate de si convendría tener una guía de términos a la hora de traducir cadenas en inglés.

La finalidad es clara: mantener una consistencia en el uso del idioma cuando hablemos de la misma cosa en distintos sitios.

Propongo pues que en las respuestas a esta pregunta vayamos consensuando términos.

<sub>Por ejemplo, podríamos añadir respuestas como propuestas y, una vez consensuadas y asumidas, borrarlas e incorporarlas a la pregunta.</sub>

Comment: Estaba ahora mismo traduciendo algunas cadenas y precisamente estaba pensando en eso. Excelente sugerencia.

Comment: @Pikoh veo por cierto que tenemos [meta-tag:terminología] y [meta-tag:glosario]. ¿Sería posible unirlas?

Comment: por supuesto. Cual te parece que dejamos como principal? Glosario tal vez?

Comment: @Pikoh sí, parece que es la que se usa de forma más "orgánica", la otra la creé yo y solo la he usado... yo (facepalm :D). Antes intenté sugerir sinónimo, nunca sé en qué sentido https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/terminolog%C3%ADa/synonyms Muchas gracias!

Comment: Ya estan unidas. He dejado glosario como etiqueta principal (efectivamente, tu sugerencia estaba al revés ;))

Comment: Uppssss gracias @Pikoh !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Partiendo del [Glosario de Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/glossary/es/), estos son los términos que consideramos *canónicos*, en donde vamos agregando los términos consensuados:

- active → activo
- answer (noun) → respuesta
- association bonus (noun) → bonificación de asociación
- badge → medalla
- bounty (noun) → recompensa
- closed (adjective) → cerrada
- Chat (noun) → Chat
- community wiki (noun) → wiki de comunidad
- data feed → feed de datos
- deleted (adjective) → eliminada
- destroy → destruir
  <sub>* se usa en relación a una cuenta, pero tiene un significado diferente de eliminar.</sub>
- downvote (noun) → voto en contra
- downvote (verb) → votar en contra
- flag (noun) → reporte
- flag (verb) → reportar
- help center (noun) → centro de ayuda
- Hot Network Questions → Preguntas populares en la red
- How (adverb) → Cómo
- hyperlink (noun) → enlace
- keyword (noun) → palabra clave
- link (noun) → enlace
- locked (adjective) → bloqueada
- markdown (noun) → markdown
- merge (verb) → combinar
- meta (noun) → meta
- not an answer → no es una respuesta
- off-topic → tema no relacionado
- on hold (adverb) → en espera
- permalink (noun) → enlace permanente
- post (noun) → publicación
- post (verb) → publicar
- posts (noun) → publicaciones
- profile (noun) →  perfil
- question (noun) → pregunta
- reopen (verb) → reabrir
- reputation (noun) → reputación
- review (noun) → revisión
  <sub>* nótese que se usa el mismo término para *revision*.</sub>
- revision (noun) → revisión
  <sub>* nótese que se usa el mismo término para *review*.</sub>
- rollback (noun) → reversión
- rollback (verb) → revertir
- room (noun) → sala
- site (noun) → sitio
- sock puppet (account) (noun) → cuenta títere
- spam (noun) → contenido no deseado
- status tags →  etiquetas de estado
- supports (verb) → admite
- syndicated → distribuido
- synonym (noun) →  sinónimo
- tag (noun) → etiqueta
- timeline (noun) → línea de tiempo
- to answer (verb) → responder
- top (adjective) → principales
  <sub>* exclusivamente para "*top questions*", "*top posts*", etc.</sub>
- Top Meta Posts (noun) → Publicaciones Populares en Meta
- Top Posts (noun) → Publicaciones Populares
- tour (noun) → recorrido
- unanswered (noun) → sin responder
- upvote (noun) → voto a favor
- upvote (verb) → votar a favor
- user (noun) → usuario
- views (noun) →  vistas
- vote (noun) → voto
- vote (verb) → votar

Comment: Acepto esta respuesta para que sea la _canónica_ y donde vayamos introduciendo las que sean consensuadas.

Answer (score 5):

Estos son algunos términos acuñados de SO. No creo que podamos obligar a nadie a usarlos, pero está bueno que se sepa cómo se pueden traducir:

- CW (Community Wiki) → wiki de comunidad
- OP (Original Poster) → autor (de la pregunta)
- TL;DR (Too long; didn't read) → resumen

Comment: Referencias de glosario: [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/209901).

Comment: Muy bueno @fedorqui. Estaría bueno ir llevando de ahí al glosario o a donde corresponda

Comment: :) ¿Solemos usar VLQ y demás para las colas?

Comment: @fedorqui no me suena eso

Comment: @lois6b es para la cola de Publicaciones de Baja Calidad. Pero vaya, si no te suena es que no se usará demasiado. Tampoco hay tanto debate en Meta como para que se haya instaurado un término "corto".

Comment: @fedorqui yo usé VLQ varias veces, pero en algún chat con alguien que entienda, usando las siglas en inglés (nunca traduje)

Comment: @Flxtr editen lo que quieran :-)

Answer (score 4):

Debatamos sobre cómo traducir estos términos:

- computer → computadora, computador, ordenador ([debate en el DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=computador)), equipo
- Community Team → Equipo de Comunidad, o queda [sin traducir](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1670/127)?
- Newsletter → boletín? Sin traducir?

Comment: voto por "distribuido" para syndicated

Comment: para mí "feed", cuando se refiere a RSS, conviene dejarlo como "feed"

Comment: para mi: **syndicated → distribuido**. *feed* lo dejaría en inglés, **data feed → feed de datos** o algo así, aunque también veo que se traduce como *fuente de datos* pero no sé si se entenderá que hablamos de RSS

Comment: En lo de *computer* no se si nos pondremos de acuerdo. En España *computador/a* suena raro y en LATAM supongo que pasa igual con *ordenador*. Cualquiera es válida pero estaría bien elegir una para todos los casos ¿Cómo lo decidimos?

Comment: /me se frota las manos con la cantidad de preguntas que saldrán para [Spanish.SE]

Comment: propongo _equipo_, _pc_ para _computer

Comment: @Pikoh he llevado el debate a Spanish.SE → [¿Existe algún término para “ordenador” y “computadora” que se entienda en todos los países?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/25781/1674)

Comment: Perfecto, tal vez alli nos den una mejor opción. Yo de momento, me quedo con _equipo_

Comment: Actualmente "question feed" está traducido como "fuente de preguntas" (véase panel derecho de esta página) y en las páginas de listas de preguntas está "recent questions feed" como "fuente de preguntas recientes". ¿Se debe agregar esto a la lista de esta respuesta, crear una nueva respuesta o cómo?

Comment: Busqué "syndicated" en Transifex y sólo aparecen dos coincidencias. En ambas me parece que el término es "syndicated data feed" y como tal debe hacerse la traducción en lugar de hacer por partes.

Comment: Estoy agregando "*Community Team*" para discutirlo.. Recién lo vi traducido en https://traducir.win/string/517, pero en inglés en [¿Quiénes forman el Community Team? ¿Qué hacen?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1670/127)

Answer (score 3):

Hay algunos términos que son nombres propios de SO y que **no** deberían traducirse:

- Developer Story
- Jobs
- Stack Exchange
- Stack Overflow
- Stack Overflow Business
- Talent
- Teams
  <sub>* *Teams* en mayúscula, *team* en minúscula se sigue traduciendo como *equipo*.</sub>

---

Términos y tecnologías que deban quedar en inglés:

- Active Directory
- commit
- Slack
- faq

Comment: Teams y Team seria igual no? El caso es que esté en mayúscula como en  https://traducir.win/string/881

Comment: @lois6b actualmente se está traduciendo a Team como Equipo. Yo no lo sé, y me da igual mientras sea coherente y se maneja el mismo

Comment: **faq** supongo que no se traduciría tampoco

Comment: @blonfu editen lo que quieran :-)

Comment: Quería plantearlo primero por si no todos estaban de acuerdo