# - "Así se hace en SOen" - "Pues en SOes no" -"Pero en español necesitamos este contenido" -"Sí, pero de esa forma no"

Tags: discusión, artículo

He observado con más o menos palabras la frase "así se hace en Stack Overflow en inglés" como reacción a votos negativos o votos de cierre y luego respuestas como "nosotros no somos iguales" y luego un ir y venir de argumentos y contra-argumentos.

Ya se ha mencionado en varias ocasiones<sup>1,2,...</sup> y de varias formas que este sitio y su comunidad no son ni serán un clon de otros. No creo que haga falta reiterar más extensamente esto pero si creo que debemos con mayor frecuencia traer las discusiones sobre lo que se permite o no a Meta, en particular, cuando están involucrados "**influencers**", es decir, usuarios que ya sea por su reputación en términos de puntos o su influencia en otros usuarios, son **ejemplo relevante** del comportamiento real de los miembros de esta comunidad..

Esto no descarta el uso de salas de chat para la discusión sincrona, sin embargo, considerando que no todos tenemos la misma disponbilidad en términos de horarios, es por ello que propongo Meta para traer al menos las conclusiones si no finales, al menos parciales, de tal forma que otros puedan abonar a las discusión en favor de formtalecer el sentido de pertenencia y el fortalecimiento de nuestra comunidad.

Lo anterior viene a colación en este momento en cierta medida por una publicación que ví ayer y esta mañana pero que al momento de redactar esto fue borrada y que no puedo consultar porque no tengo los privilegios para ello, pero esa publicación es sólo un ejemplo de otras tantas.

En síntesis, **usemos más Meta**.

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup> [¿Son aceptables las traducciones de preguntas de StackOverflow en inglés?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/46/65)
- <sup>2</sup> [¡Bienvenidos a este su sitio!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146/65)

Comment: Bien dicho, debemos usar más Meta para este tipo de discusión tal y como lo haces aquí.

Comment: *Así se hace en Corea del norte* - *Pues en Chiquitistán no*. No lo entiendo ¡ambos son países! ¿¡no deberían funcionar igual!?

Comment: Corea del Norte igual no es el mejor ejemplo, pero si comparamos dos países de Europa o de Latinoamérica pues si tendrán muchas cosas en común salvo peculiaridades. Deberíamos tener bastante de SOen pero con nuestras peculiaridades, tampoco es hacernos un calco sin sentido de nuestro homónimo anglosajón.

Comment: @Eduardorq comparemos Chiquitistán con Bequelar pues :)

Comment: Sin querer restarle importancia al planteamiento que hace @Rubén, que me parece MUY interesante su planteamiento, pero incluso si nos damos cuenta hay países dentro del mismo continente y formas de gobierno muy dispares. Chiquitistán puede ser una república y Bequelar una dictadura (el cruel príncipe ya se hizo mayor). Nos guste o no SOen nos lleva años luz porque hay contenido que aun está allí y no en SOes, aprender de lo bueno que tienen y mejorar en otros aspectos.

Comment: En cuanto a las reglas del sitio, me parece que vale la pena recordar que SO "en inglés" no es un país, ahí colaboran desarrolladores de todos los países, sólo que se comunican en Inglés. También que este sitio no es otra cosa, es SO, localizado en español.  Entonces, si todo el mundo (en SO en inglés), admite seguir las reglas ya consensuadas, cuál es la necesidad de inventar la rueda? Realmente pensamos que la vamos a hacer más redonda?

Comment: @Juan: No sé si leíste mi comentario previo.Estaba por agregar los enlaces pero luego me dí cuenta que estamos en "canales distintos". ¿Has leído [¡Bienvenidos a este su sitio!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146/65)?

Comment: @Ruben, No lo había leído, lo leí ahora. Comparto lo que dice el post,  en lo que se quiere lograr, aunque lo de la identidad única exagera un poco: el logo es igual, tienen el mismo nombre, y son parte de stack exchange, y si se abrió este foro en español es porque el que funciona en inglés anda muy bien. Con esto lo que me parece es que no se trata de un clon sino de un hijo, que puede aprender del padre las cosas que hace bien o hacerse el rebelde y como dije querer re-inventar la rueda.

Comment: @Juan: Que bueno que lo has leído y que compartes lo que dice el post que te referí, además gracias por compartir tus impresiones. Comparto en que aquel anda muy bien y lo que lo hace andar muy bien es su comunidad y lo que hace la comunidad, es primero participar en el sitio principal y luego participar en Meta. Esta es "la rueda" que no hay que reinventar.